# How to combine meta_query and post__in in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have built a complex query which should do 3 things:

1. select posts with ids in the $additional_ids array using post__in;
2. ignore posts with ids in the $ignore_ids array using post__not_in;
3. select posts with a combination of cpt values (ie. is an animal, is blue and eats grass) using meta_query.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$args_assets = array(
        'post_type' => 'assets',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in' => $additional_ids,
        'post__not_in' => $ignore_ids,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            $query_animal,
            $query_color,
            $query_food,
        ),
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc',
        );
```

The query works fine WTHOUT the 'post__in' => $additional_ids line. As soon as I add the post__in argument, the query returns an empty result.

Is it possible to combine post__in with a meta_query? If so, what's the best method?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Seeing a typo in your `post__not_in` value.  Var name is misspelled?

Comment: Comment out all your query args except the meta query and see what you get.  Looks like a format problem in the args of your meta.   The `$query_animal` and others should be in an array.

Comment: @jdm2112 $query_animals etc are arrays. If I comment out post__in everything works which makes me wonder if there's a problem with my logic. The query should select the post__in IDs AND the ids from my meta_query. Perhaps the relation between post__in and meta_query is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`post__in` and `post__not_in` are mutually exclusive.

> Note: you cannot combine `post__in` and `post__not_in` in the same query.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Either make the query with `post__in` and `meta_query` combination or make the query with `post__not_in` and `meta_query` combination. Any of them but not the union of them.